# Image quality poor after loading into Image control in comparison to original

Tags: delphi

I got an app that loads images into the Zimage(graphcontrol). One issue I am having is the original image is a lot better quality than the one that ends up showing in the component. The one showing looks like it has random black marks on it.  So what i do:

- load image from folder into TJpegimage
- assign jpg to a bitmap
- save bitmap to object list
- repeat that above until all images are loaded into object list
- Then i create a bitmap
- assign first image in object list to it
- draw the bitmap on canvas.

but it just looks a lot worse than the original. Any help or idea on this?

This is the loading code.

```
    procedure TForm1.LoadImages(const Dir: string);
var
  i: Integer;
  CurFileName: string;
  JpgIn: TJPEGImage;
  BmpOut: TBitmap;
begin

//set up progress bar
 progressbar1.Min := 0;
 progressbar1.Max := GetFilesCount(dir,'*.*');
 Label3.Visible := true;
 progressbar1.Visible := true;
//sets array for length
  SetLength(hwArray,GetFilesCount(dir,'*.*'));
//sets index for object list
  CurIdx := -1;
  i := 0;
  while True do
  begin
//gets file name out of current folder
    CurFileName := Format('%s%d.jpg',
                          [IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Dir), i]);
    if not FileExists(CurFileName) then
      Break;
//count files in folder for progress bar.
     progressbar1.StepBy(1);
//creates jpgin
    JpgIn := TJPEGImage.Create;
    try
//loads jpgin with file
      JpgIn.LoadFromFile(CurFileName);
//creates TBitmap and sets width to same as jpgs
      BmpOut := TBitmap.Create;
      bmpout.Width := jpgin.Width;
      bmpout.Height := jpgin.Height;
     try
         BmpOut.Assign(JpgIn);
//adds 1 to index for object list. thus starting at 0
         curIdx := curIdx+1;
//add bitmap to objectlist
         CurIdx:= mylist.Add(TBitmap(bmpout));
         hwArray[CurIdx][0]:=jpgin.Width;
         hwArray[CurIdx][1]:=jpgin.height;

      finally
      end;
    finally
      JpgIn.Free;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end;
//makes sure cout is above 0 thus files added
  if mylist.Count > 0 then
  begin
      try
      CurIdx := 0;
      getBitmapfromList(CurIdx,bmpout);
      ZImage1.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);
       //image1.Canvas.Assign(bmpout);
    finally
       BmpOut.Free;
    end;
  end;
  Label3.Visible := false;
  progressbar1.Visible := false;
  page:= '0';
  zimage1.DblClick;
end;
```

function get bit map from list

```
procedure Tform1.getBitmapfromList(index:integer;var Bitm:TBitmap);
begin
     Bitm.Assign(TBitmap(mylist[index]));
     if (Bitm.Width<>hwArray[index][0]) OR (Bitm.Height<>hwArray[index][1]) then begin
        ShowMessage('Size differs');
        Bitm.Width:=hwArray[index][0];
        Bitm.Height:=hwArray[index][1];
     end;
end;
```

Next button to view next image

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  BmpOut: TBitmap;
begin
bmpout := TBitmap.Create;
CurIdx:= strtoint(page);
getBitmapfromList(CurIdx,bmpout);
ZImage1.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);
//image1.Canvas.Assign(bmpout);
page := inttostr(strtoint(page) +1);      //this should show next item in ilst?
zimage1.Repaint;
end;
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Here are the images:

http://s7.postimage.org/48mectvsp/image_Difference.png

## EDIT

It seems like once i zoom in on an image it gets better. the worst quility is when its full screen/zoomed all the way out.. original size.

Comment: Can you attach the original and loaded image to the question plz?

Comment: I Haven't used the TBitmap class, so I might be wrong but, it seems you are reusing the last TBitmap instance inserted into the collection, which already has an image assigned, to have a new image reassigned and shown. Don't you need to use FreeImage before that? And couldn't that be an issue if you only have one image?

Comment: @Guillem, adding image to the collection, assigning between `TBitmap` instances and rendering it on canvas cannot decrease the image quality. Glen, I guess your problem is in a wrong aspect ratio when you are rendering the image (if am I right you are using `StretchDraw`). And of course you need to take into account that when you are stretching the image (zoom), it naturaly loses the quality (you would have to resample it somehow to reduce the quality lose).

Comment: http://postimage.org/image/6py5k3fp3/  thats a link to the two images next to each other.  I have not used stretchdraw any were in project if you look at the link for the images , its clearly not a zooming issue as the picture is save size as the one next to it. At that point i had yet to zoom

Comment: change `Image1.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);` to `Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);`

Comment: you forget to set `ZImage1.Height:=bmpout.Heigt` and `ZImage1.Width:=bmpout.Width` before `ZImage1.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);`

Comment: using TImage it does seem to look better but its extra large. I assume the zimage1 would look the same at the same zoom level. I could not get the iamge to show full view inside the TImage   Let me set the zimage height width.

Comment: it  seems like its ok till it starts to zoom out to a certin point. could it be a setting in the pixels?  adding zimage1.height did not help image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- a) I assume that all images have a different size. If the displayed image "ZImage1"  should have always the same **height or width** (one of two things, or it is made ​​with stretch fit == low quality) must be determined ratio (orginal.height / original.width).Then "ZImage1" (either height or width) must **calculated** in the new relationship.
- b) Set ZImage1.AutoSize:=false;
- c) Set ZImage1.Stretch:=false;
- d) bmpout.Width and Height must set to the current `mylist[CurIdx]` size.

> ```
> bmpout.Assign(TBitmap(mylist[CurIdx]));
> Zimage1.Bitmap.Width := bmpout.Width;
> Zimage1.Bitmap.Height := bmpout.Height;
> ZImage1.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);
> ```

NOTE:

You did **NOT** **assign** to mylist .. you **store** it CurIdx:= mylist.Add(TBitmap(bmpout));

I can not see how you have created "mylist".

Maybe that's the reason, if you want it back with `bmpout.Assign(TBitmap(mylist[CurIdx]));`, perhaps there is **no automatic** set bmpout.Width and bmpout.Height.

TIP:

create an extra array to store height and width.

```
....
JpgIn.LoadFromFile(CurFileName);
BmpOut := TBitmap.Create;
bmpout.Width := jpgin.Width;
bmpout.Height := jpgin.Height;
....
CurIdx:= mylist.Add(TBitmap(bmpout));
hwArray[CurIdx][0]:=jpgin.Width;
hwArray[CurIdx][1]:=jpgin.height;
....
```

make a procedure
**EDIT**: put a test into it;

```
procedure getBitmapfromList(index:integer;var Bitm:TBitmap);
begin
     Bitm.Assign(TBitmap(mylist[index]));
     if (Bitm.Width<>hwArray[index][0]) OR (Bitm.Height<>hwArray[index][1]) then begin
        ShowMessage('Size differs');
        Bitm.Width:=hwArray[index][0];
        Bitm.Height:=hwArray[index][1];
     end;
end;
```

call it with:

```
....
getBitmapfromList(CurIdx,bmpout);
....
ZImage1.Bitmap.Assign(bmpout);
....
```

**EDIT:** Create **hwArray**

```
type
  Tarray2size = Array[0..1] of integer;
.... 

var
  hwArray : Array of Tarray2size;
....

procedure TForm1.LoadImages(const Dir: string);
....
begin
 //set up progress bar
 progressbar1.Min := 0;
 showmessage(inttostr(GetFilesCount(dir,'*.*')));
 SetLength(hwArray,GetFilesCount(dir,'*.*'));
....
```

Comment: There's no need to set the bitmap size nor use an array to store the image dimensions. This pseudocode `SecondBitmap.Assign(FirstBitmap);` will set the size of the `SecondBitmap` by the `FirstBitmap`. This question is IMHO more about aspect ratio or scaling quality.

Comment: It now runs, But image still looks bad, But I did notice something. If i zoom in the image becomes cleaner. it seems only to be bad quality while its zoomed out to full screen

Comment: i am using XE , but idont see scaled either. As far as putting it on a Timage i tried to change zimage1.bitmap.assign(bmpout); but it gives errors about Timage not being able to assign bitmap. I have updated code to show what i have got up till now.. with your improvements.also when it first loads it shows about 1/4 of the image with the rest hidden only viewable by scroll bars. not sure if that helps any?

Comment: After redoing everything using this code, I can varify the code is right and does everything requested. It seems my zimage has some calculation issues.  The problem being in my  TZImage.Paint method. I think i am not preserving the aspect ratio correctly.The on-screen image always fills the control's client area regardless of the shape of the form or the source image, so the aspect ratio cannot possibly be preserved.

Comment: The calculations in TZImage.Paint are incorrect. I tested by simply changeing the paint method to 

    Canvas.Draw(0,0,FBitmap);

and it produced a high quality image, the same as the original. Hence it must be the calculations in TZImage.Paint that are wrong.  It is just the aspect ratio calculations that are wrong. So with that i will approve this answer as it does answer the orginal question. but i may post another about how to fix my paint method... Thanks glen